# DC/OS Mesosphere install/deploy my own application across a cluster

Tags: mesosphere, dcos

I am trying to deploy my own cluster using DC/OS CLI installation. Mesosphere has a huge support as there are many packages ready to install provided in Mesosphere Universe repo (https://github.com/mesosphere/universe).

However, I would like to make one step further. I am trying to install my own applications to my cluster using the DC/OS CLI installation process. To do this, as far as I understand, I need to either (i) make my application recognizable to the system repo (as the other repo packages that are provided in Universe) or (ii) make a new image that consists all my applications and modify the DC/OS script to make the installation possible.

Unfortunately, my modest knowledge is flawed and I could not find any where a clear answer to this.
Therefore, I would like to ask:

1) Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

2) If the answer is YES, how exactly should I do? My goal is to install my awesome apps for my own purpose, not to publish them. But to add my apps as repo into Universe, it seems like I have to publish them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is possible! :)
2. Please follow [these instructions](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/deploying-services/creating-services/)

Comment: Thanks, Judith. I am aware of this way of application deployment. However, I am not sure it is the best way to deploy a distributed application, which has to be deployed across the cluster and each instance on each node has local configuration. I think it would be better to have it installed on every node. Then the way of deployment that you mentioned is used to launch the application. What do you think?

Comment: Perhaps you could develop your package as described [here](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/developing-services/), and then publish it to a [local universe](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.11/administering-clusters/deploying-a-local-dcos-universe/) rather than the public one?

Comment: Great! I think this is what I really need. BTW, when I installed DC/OS on my small cluster, I would like to have nodes which are both master and agent that they can also run apps. However, the requirement mentioned that the master and agent **private** ips must not contain duplicate. In this case, do I need to create VIPs on the same physical node for each master and agent?

Comment: It _might_ be technically possible to run master and agent on the same node but I'm not sure how you would do it and it's _really really_ [not recommended](https://github.com/dcos/community/wiki/DC%5COS-FAQ#installation). If you're just playing around and trying to save space you might look into [DC/OS Vagrant](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant), which is not for production use :)

Comment: Well, I am aware of all of this. The point is that it barely makes sense to me. The core value of Mesos is to efficiently use the resources. And I believe that it should be able to manage the resources itself to mitigate the interference between processes when collocating Master and Agent. People asked for it and they agreed to take it into consideration. But the plan is defined as this feature will come **eventually** [link](https://dcosjira.atlassian.net/browse/DCOS-474)

Comment: Currently, I am deploying HBase on my DC/OS cluster. Since HBase need Zookeeper for HA, it requires to have Zookeeper running on HMaster nodes. If DC/OS allows collocating master and agent node, that would be no problem. HMaster will simply use the Zookeeper for DC/OS master process for master monitoring and election. However, it is not the case, HMaster cannot run on the same node with DC/OS master node. Therefore, it requires extra Zookeeper processes with different configuration. Have you ever experienced this? Do you have any idea of how we can solve this?

Comment: I'd suggest running a separate zookeeper cluster. I haven't personally tried it, but there is a [Portworx tutorial](https://docs.portworx.com/scheduler/mesosphere-dcos/zookeeper.html) that might help or that you could at least model your deployment after. This is pretty far afield from your original question, so if you run into further technical challenges I'd recommend asking on the DC/OS Mailing list or community slack, both of which you can find via our [community page](https://dcos.io/community/).